# How to convert line to path in SVG

Tags: svg

I have a line in svg

```
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20"
      stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

How can I convert this into path?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d The ones you want are `M` and `L`.

Comment: Thanks!<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M20 100 L100 20"  stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
</svg>

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of an online tool for doing this, but you can do it manually, if you know what the contents of the path "d" attribute mean.

M: "Move To"
L: "Line To"
C: "Cubic Bezier To"
Q: "Quadratic Bezier To"
Z: "Close path"

for lines, you will only need "M" and "L".

So, to convert this line:

```
<line x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="20"/>
```

the path equivalent would be:

```
<path d="M20 100, L100 20" />
```

or, d="**M**x1 y1, **L**x2 y2"

Comment: This should actually convert to <path d="M 20 100 L 100 20" />. Some more info on the commands and syntax is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: Note that this doesn't consider the stroke-width attribute of the line!